# Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph

Tags: jenkins

Got several Jenkins job. But when ever we run them, we get stuck for 15-20 minutes at following:

Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph

Following is the complete log:

> In progress
>   Console Output
>   Started by user *****
>   Building remotely on ****server in workspace *****workspace
>   git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url *****
>   Fetching upstream changes from *****
>   git --version
>   using GIT_SSH to set credentials *****
>   git fetch --tags --progress **** +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   git rev-parse origin/***^{commit}
>
>   Checking out Revision ** (origin/****)
>
>   git config core.sparsecheckout
>
>   git checkout -f *****
>
>   First time build. Skipping changelog.
>
>   [*****] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson***.sh
>   + rm -rf .repository/com/****
>   Parsing POMs
>   using settings config with name **** Settings
>   Downloaded artifact ******.pom
>   Downloaded artifact ******.pom
>   Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph

My question is how to remove or shorten this wait time during dependency graph calculation.